# Why does State remains unchanged after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to show/hide a modal when a user clicks on a item inside a list. The modal shows up as planned but cannot be hidden. When `_dismiss()` is called, `setState` executes but when I `console.log` the `state` inside the callback, the parameter `show` is still *true*.

Why is this happening?

**Message.jsx**

```
export default class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };

        this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
        this._dismiss = this._dismiss.bind(this);
    }

    _onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            show: true
        })
    }

    _dismiss() {
        this.setState({
            show: false
        }, function () {
            console.log(this.state) // logs: Object {show: true}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this._onClick} className="message">
                <Modal show={this.state.show} close={this._dismiss}>
                    <h1>...</h1>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Modal.jsx**

```
export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._onClose = this._onClose.bind(this);
    }

    _onClose() {
        this.props.close()
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.show) {
            return (
                <div className="modal" onClick={this._onClose} >
                    <div className="content">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way to work these out is usually to console.log() something out in the handler functions which will then quickly tell you the way they're being called and how often etc.  Usually problems can be seen there.  Clearly if you set state and check state in the callback and it's already changed then one or more of your handlers must be being called unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div is still getting on `onClick` events event when its children are clicked. I suspect `_dismiss` is being called and then `_onClick` is being called. React batches `setState` calls so it ends up setting `show` back to `true`.

Remedies.

If the close callback of handler give you the event as an argument. Call `e.stopPropagation()` or From @richsilv in the comments `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Or if it doesn't pass the event. Check in the `_onClick` if `show` is true or false. If it is true, don't `setState`

Comment: Or don't put the modal inside the `.message` and the event won't bubble up to it.

Comment: Or even add an `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to the modal's `_onClose`.

Comment: @richsilv or that. I didn't know his reasoning for doing it that way.

Comment: @richsilv thanks for `stopImmediatePropagation` I didn't know that existed! I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: amazing, it was driving me crazy. Thank you very much guys!